# iOS 9.2 missing Profile section from General Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I was trying to activate a developer app in iOS 9.2 and the app was not trusted due to security settings.  I tried to go into the Profile area under General Settings, but it wasn't there.  What gives?  It was there this morning . . .

Comment: Device Management is missing on iPhone 5 updated to IOS 9.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple renamed the Profile section to Device Management.  It is still under General Settings and performs the same function.

Answer (score 2):

This somewhat worked for me: Instead of looking in the device, go to XCode, Devices (Under Window), ctrl -click on the device and you should see a "Show Provisioning Profiles" menu item.

Comment: that "Show Provisioning Profiles" option disabled for me, is there anyway to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I couldn't debug my apps anymore.
I used the Apple Configurator (https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) to delete all of my profiles on the iPhone. Afterwards I installed another signed app again and now I can debug again.

But I still can't see "Device Management" in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful doing this when I accidentally went to Product>Profile once the build is finished head over to your phone then Settings>General> then the Device Management will instantly appear under VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I am at iOS 12.1.2(16C101) and was trying to verify that the Developer App certificate for my account is trusted on my device. Found the option at

General -> Profiles & Device Management.

Answer (score -1):

If "Device Management" doesn't appear you must restart your device to see it.
This worked on ios 9.

Comment: This had no effect for me either.

Comment: This works for me on ios 9 but they changed it on ios 10